# Switching directories in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have written my project in some directory `d` . I have a huge set of testcases . So I would like to put them in an internal directory `din` of `d` . Also I would like to store the output files in `dout` . How to achieve this ?

For now a part of my makefile looks like :

```
test:
     ./a.out  < input1.c  > output1.txt
     ./a.out  < input2.c  > output2.txt
     .
     .
     .
     .
     ./a.out  < inputn.c  > outputn.txt
```

(n is known)

`make test` now executes the program .

edit:
    < >  are corrected in the question

Comment: Are you talking about just having `input#.c` and `output#.txt` (though your file names are backwards aren't they?) in the `din/` directory and fixing those commands to match? Because that's just putting `din/` at the start of each of those filenames (and moving the files into the directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subdirectory `din`. Put your `Makefile` to run the tests in there.

In the main directory's `Makefile`, enter the rule

```
test:
    $(MAKE) -C din test
```

I would also rewrite your existing `Makefile`.

First of all, you don't want to repeat the same thing for every file. You can use a pattern rule here.  So the rule becomes

```
output%.txt: input%.c
    a.out < $< > $@
```

Now how to make the `test` target depend on every output file?

It would be great if there was a construct to list every file that can be made from an existing file using the above rule, but there isn't.  However, we can take the list of existing files ending in `.c` and convert it to the corresponding output files with GNU Make's [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-wildcard-2) and [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) functions, although it is ugly:

```
test: $(patsubst output%,input%,$(patsubst %.c,%.txt,$(wildcard *.c)))
```

Now, you have only two rules and one command.

Comment: Thank you .. It helped a lot

Comment: Thank you for your edit suggestion. Someone else rejected it, but I've applied it.